# Premake5 android makefile declare prebuilt library

Tags: premake

Using premake5 file to generate make files for android. I am trying to produce the prebuilt library declaration as described in https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html

More precisely

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

What kind of project would introduce the include include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) or what other option do I need to include?

Answer (score 0):

I have little knowledge in this, but I was able to use android PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY - in premake4 using the following lua script:
The script is customised for the example you've give above.

```
linklibs = {"foo"}
libdirpaths = {"../../path/to/libs/"}

project "project_using_foo"
        language        "C"
        kind            "SharedLib"
        files           (android.srcfiles)
        includedirs     (includepaths)
        location        "build"
        links           (linklibs)
        libdirs         (libdirpaths)
        buildoptions    (buildoptions)
        androidappabi   {"armeabi-v7a"}
        androidsdk      "android-19"
```

where libfoo.so will be in ../../path/to/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfoo.so
[$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI) in this case is "armeabi-v7a"]